# How to access previous element when using yield in for loop chisel3

Tags: scala, chisel

This is mix Chisel / Scala question.
Background, I need to sum up a lot of numbers (the number of input signals in configurable). Due to timing constrains I had to split it to groups of 4 and pipe(register it), then it is fed into next stage (which will be 4 times smaller, until I reach on)
this is my code:

```
// log4 Aux function //
def log4(n : Int): Int = math.ceil(math.log10(n.toDouble) / math.log10(4.0)).toInt
// stage //
def Adder4PipeStage(len: Int,in: Vec[SInt]) : Vec[SInt] = {
    require(in.length % 4 == 0) // will not work if not a muliplication of 4
    val pipe = RegInit(VecInit(Seq.fill(len/4)(0.S(in(0).getWidth.W))))
    pipe.zipWithIndex.foreach {case(p,j) => p := in.slice(j*4,(j+1)*4).reduce(_ +& _)}
    pipe
}
// the pipeline
val adderPiped = for(j <- 1 to log4(len)) yield Adder4PipeStage(len/j,if(j==1) io.in else <what here ?>)
```

how to I access the previous stage, I am also open to hear about other ways to implement the above

Comment: I am afraid you can't access the previous stage. `for` with `->` in scala is translated to `flatMap` and it is making operations on elements of the collection independently. You would have to use `foldLeft` instead of the `for`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things you could do here:

1. You could just use a `var` for the "previous" value:

```scala
var prev: Vec[SInt] = io.in
val adderPiped = for(j <- 1 to log4(len)) yield {
  prev = Adder4PipeStage(len/j, prev) 
  prev
}
```

It is a little weird using a `var` with a `for yield` (since the former is fundamentally mutable while the latter tends to be used with immutable-style code).

2. You could alternatively use a fold building up a `List`

```scala
// Build up backwards and reverse (typical in functional programming)
val adderPiped = (1 to log4(len)).foldLeft(io.in :: Nil) {
  case (pipes, j) => Adder4PipeStage(len/j, pipes.head) :: pipes
}.reverse
 .tail // Tail drops "io.in" which was 1st element in the result List
```

If you don't like the backwards construction of the previous fold,

3. You could use a fold with a `Vector` (better for appending than a `List`):

```scala
val adderPiped = (1 to log4(len)).foldLeft(Vector(io.in)) {
  case (pipes, j) => pipes :+ Adder4PipeStage(len/j, pipes.last)
}.tail // Tail drops "io.in" which was 1st element in the result Vector
```

Finally, if you don't like these immutable ways of doing it, you could always just embrace mutability and write something similar to what one would in Java or Python:

4. For loop and mutable collection

```scala
val pipes = new mutable.ArrayBuffer[Vec[SInt]]
for (j <- 1 to log4(len)) {
  pipes += Adder4PipeStage(len/j, if (j == 1) io.in else pipes.last)
}
```